# Is there a way for establishing a connection pool in Redis c++?

Tags: c++, redis, connection-pooling

I am new to Redis, have been working with the Redis driver

> https://github.com/Cylix/cpp_redis/wiki/Examples.

I have made an application in C++, the problem I am encountering is that I keep opening the connection for every query and this process is expensive. I wanted to know if I could make a pool of connections in Redis?

Comment: You can try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) which supports connection pool. *Disclaimer*: I'm the author of this Redis client library.

Comment: If you are still unsatisfied with the existing solutions (no pool, or no pool with policy which you need), you can write your own using [bredis](https://github.com/basiliscos/cpp-bredis/).